# Iterating through structure with indexes in VB

Tags: vb.net, data-structures, iteration

I am trying to iterate through a structure by using index. Is there an easy way to do it apart from reflection?

The sample of code;

```
For j As Integer = 0 To usedRange.ColumnCount - 1
            ws.Cells(0, j).FillColor = Drawing.Color.DarkTurquoise
Next
```

Let's say I try to assign a different color to each cell using the current index value, like Drawing.Color(j)

Comment: That's not a 'data structure' it's a set of cells from an Excel worksheet. It would hep of you reworded the question as it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Ditto. What does ws represent? Looks like you may be iterating just fine through the cells (depending on what ws is.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to enumerate colors:

```
    ' Get all the values from the KnownColor enumeration.
    Dim colorsArray As System.Array = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(KnownColor))
    Dim allColors(colorsArray.Length) As KnownColor
    Array.Copy(colorsArray, allColors, colorsArray.Length - 1)
    With dgvColors
        .ReadOnly = True
        .Columns.Add("ColorName", "ColorName")
        For i = 0 To allColors.Length - 1
            .Rows.Add(allColors(i).ToString)
            .Rows(i).Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(allColors(i))
        Next
        .Columns("ColorName").Width = 500
        .Rows.RemoveAt(.Rows.Count - 2) ' delete - bug in arrays
        .Rows.RemoveAt(.Rows.Count - 2) ' delete - bug in arrays
        .ClearSelection()
    End With
```

This is a hack adding colors to a DataGridView - not sure this is legit code, I just use it as a utility.